# Quadtree decomposition on non square image

Tags: tree, quadtree, decomposition

Does anyone know the best way to perform Quadtree decomposition on a non square image? I keep getting lines appearing across my image which is drawn using a Quadtree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing would probably be to imagine that your image is embedded in a square image (placed centrally, so that bisection of the larger image corresponds to bisection of the smaller one). When drawing it, of course you'd then need to avoid drawing bits that aren't actually within the image rectangle, but I'd have thought the special-case code needed for that would be simpler than the special-case code needed to handle non-square images.

Without more information about just what you're doing and just what's going wrong, I don't think there's much prospect of debugging your lines-appearing-across-the-image problem. (Is it possible that the underlying problem there is that your size isn't a power of 2, rather than that it's not square? In other words, that something isn't being done quite right when bisecting the image produces "halves" of different sizes?)

Comment: ok so i have it working now - got rid of the lines. How do i stop it from drawing parts that aren't in the image? As it is capturing the black area around the image as a result of making the area square.

Comment: the lines were due to the size of the image (not being a power of two) I modified it but now my quadtree stores redundant information and when retrieving depth info on the image i am faced with false data...